# DropdownListSelectedValue to Label

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I keep on getting the Name instead of the Price.What I want is I pick a value on The DropdownList and Load its price on the label.

```
private void GetData()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = MejOnlineManagementDB00;Integrated Security=True;");
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT price
                                            FROM Products3
                                            WHERE productName='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + "'", connection);
    SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        lblPrice.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
    connection.Close();
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblPrice.Text=DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
}
```

above is my selectedIndex.

Comment: *lblPrice.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();* look at that, you're using the DropDown value, not the read one from the DB...

Comment: ``lblPrice.Text = rdr["price"];``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code into this:

```
        private void GetData()
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = MejOnlineManagementDB00;Integrated Security=True;");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT price
                                                FROM Products3
                                                WHERE productName='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + "'", connection);
            SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            if(dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    lblPrice.Text = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString(); //  if price is  string use GetString(0))
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

**EDIT:**

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData(); 
    }
```

Comment: Hi what should i Put inside my selected index   protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblPrice.Text=DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
        }

Comment: @rai nalasa Use lblPrice.Text = rdr.GetInt32(0).ToString() instead

Comment: I cant use lblPrice.Text = rdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();            Inside my protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: @rai nalasa For getting data from reader and assigning to text you have to use this method instead. Right now you are getting the value of dropdownlist value and assigning it to the label lblPrice.

Comment: I copied Your code.But it still give me the Name instead of price.I Updated my question.Can you see if there is something wrong with my DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: @rai nalasa rdr.Read() will loop through the rows. In each iteration the value will change and you have to get that value. But you are not trying to get it. Instead you are getting it from dropDownList.

Comment: @rai nalasa If you clearly say your need i will definitely solve this. I din get your exact need

Comment: Sorry bro.Ok ill try to say it clearly.What I need Is whenever I pick a value on my dropdownlist It will Load its PRICE on my label which is lblprice.Right now I am getting the name instead of the price while using the code you gave me.

Comment: @ noxius.my Price is float btw.

Comment: @rai nalasa Do you need price from database or from dropdownlist

Comment: the logic of the  code you gave me was what i need and Yeah Price is stored in my Database.Whenever I select a value on my Dropdownlist  which is the productname.It will load its price from the database to label.

Comment: @rai nalasa for that purpose you have to modify some code.

Comment: @rai nalasa i ll do it

Comment: really appreciate it.

Comment: @rai nalsa use GetFloat(0) for float

Comment: im getting this error An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: ok ill try this.Should you see my dropdownlist codes as well?

Comment: dude ITS WORKING THANKS REALLY NEEDED THIS.

Comment: @rai nalasa Good Luck bro